# Why won't my HTTP request in Flutter work?

Tags: http, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm making an HTTP request to an API I am currently hosting locally. I am getting this error at the moment. In the function, '1' will print but not '2'.

```
Future<http.Response> fetchUserData() async{
 print('1');
 final response = await http.get('http://localhost:5000/getUser/7890');
 print('2');
 return response;
}
```

This is how I'm calling the function

```
var testVar = fetchUserData();
print(testVar);
```

The error I get is

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
dart:sdk_internal 124039:30                           get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart.lib.js 214:124  <fn>
dart:sdk_internal 37029:58                            runUnary
dart:sdk_internal 32116:29                            handleValue
dart:sdk_internal 32663:49                            handleValueCallback
dart:sdk_internal 32701:17                            _propagateToListeners
dart:sdk_internal 32535:25                            [_complete]
dart:sdk_internal 37439:24                            _cancelAndValue
dart:sdk_internal 18487:17                            <fn>
  dart:sdk_internal 4673:16                             _checkAndCall
  dart:sdk_internal 4678:17                             dcall
  dart:sdk_internal 104576:23                           <fn>
at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:53647/dart_sdk.js:4477:12)
at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:53647/dart_sdk.js:37464:16)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:53647/dart_sdk.js:37458:13)
at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:53647/dart_sdk.js:37290:13)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:53647/dart_sdk.js:37296:13)
```

Wondering if someone spots a mistake.

Comment: Just try it using the local ip said by @Danny or just check it using the 10.0.0.0 instead of localhost, I was also stuck for this problem the 10.0.0.0 worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was a problem on the API side.
Add these lines to the top of your API if you're using Flask.

```
from flask_cors import CORS
CORS(app=app)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your Flutter app in an emulator/mobile device but you're running your local web server on your PC, `localhost` isn't the correct hostname to use. On a mobile device (for example) that would point back at the mobile device itself.

Try replacing `localhost` with the (network) IP address of your machine instead (and ensure any firewall will allow the connection).